# Doctrine2 Postgres JSONB how to search

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, postgresql-9.3, jsonb

I am using Postgres JSONB, in order to store bunch of properties in one field for one complex system.

Where I have one field, that is called properties and properties do have trees of objects.

Here is the small piece of data from properties.

```
{
    "urls": [],
    "games": false,
    "images": [],
    "rating": null,
    "founded": 0,
    "bannedIn": ["00000000-0000-0000-8888-000000000001",
    "00000000-0000-0000-8888-000000000002"],
    "comments": "",
    "chat": false
}
```

In table I have some objects those has bannedIn set to some guids, some object has empty array and some objects don't has bannedIn property at all.

Now I am trying to get every row where bannedIn contains `"00000000-0000-0000-8888-000000000001"` (WORKS)

When I try to get every row where bannedIn doesn't contains `"00000000-0000-0000-8888-000000000001"` (WORKS)

But When I query to count all where properties doesn't has bannedIn at all it fallback with 0 count, even though I have 1K object with out bannedIn.

WORKS

```
$builder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('e')
    ->from(Entity::class, 'e')
    ->where('e.otherObject = :guid')->setParameter('guid', $guid)
    ->andWhere('GET_JSON_FIELD(e.properties, \'bannedIn\') LIKE ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, '%00000000-0000-0000-8888-000000000001%');
```

Is there a way to query jsonb where key does not exist?
I have also tried following, didn't work.
The ? operator is implemented by calling its function `jsonb_exists(column_name, value)`